# Using a random number to encrypt a message

Tags: haskell, encryption, random, monads

I'm currently trying to encrypt a message (String) with the help of a random generated number in Haskell. The idea is to get the message, generate a random String of numbers with the same length (or more and then to take the length I need).

Then i want to perform some actions based on the ASCII representation and then return the encrypted String.

Unfortunately I'm not very versed with monads in Haskell, so it might be a very simple problem to solve, which I can't comprehend yet.

```
generateMyKey string = newStdGen >>= \x ->  print $ concatMap show $ map abs $ rs x
                    where rs x = randomlist (length string) x

randomlist :: Int -> StdGen -> [Int]
randomlist n = take n . unfoldr (Just . random)
```

So the problem is I get an IO() out of getMyKey, but I want to have a String, or atleast a IO(String) to perform the encrypting mechanism.

Right now I'm getting a big list of positive (hence the abs + map) random numbers, but I can't access them.

Comment: Have you tried to replace `print` (`print :: IO ()`) by `return` (`return :: (Monad m) => a -> m a`)? (Hint: IO is a monad.)

Comment: The only way I got it to work is (with your change) :                               print $ unsafePerformIO $! getMyKey $! "sampletext" But that seems like a very bad solution.

Comment: @Cirquit Never use `unsafePerformIO`, it is not for every day Haskell programming!  It's an advanced function for circumventing the type system for performance reasons or for when interfacing with an external library.  If you use it in your code, you'll run into subtle bugs that might only show up later, and you'll be essentially throwing away the safety that Haskell gives you.  If you want `getMyKey` to generate a random number, it's going to have to have a return type of `IO String` (or `IO something`), there's no way around it.

Comment: Or take an additional `StdGen` to have `generateMyKey :: StdGen -> String -> String` (although `(StdGen,String)` as return would be more appropriate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of solutions to this problem, but at first glance it might seem that you need to have your entire program operate in the IO monad, but you don't! The entry (/exit) point of your program is the only place that needs to see `IO` -- you can factor out any transformations on your random list into pure functions, i.e:

```
import Data.List
import System.Random

generateMyKey :: String -> IO String
generateMyKey string = do
  x <- newStdGen
  let rs = randomlist (length string)
  return $ concatMap show $ map abs $ rs x

randomlist :: Int -> StdGen -> [Int]
randomlist n = take n . unfoldr (Just . random)

change :: String -> String
change = reverse -- for example

main :: IO ()
main = do
  key <- generateMyKey "what"
  putStrLn $ change key
```

`generateMyKey` is identical to what you had before, except that it's written in do notation now and is returning the string instead of just printing it. This allows us to "pull out" a random key from inside the `IO` monad and transform it with regular pure functions, like `change`, for example. This allows you to reason about the pure functions as normal, while still pulling in your values from `IO`.

Answer (score 4):

There are two basic ways to go about this (and one more complicated but easier).  If you're just using `System.Random`, you can generate random numbers in two ways, either by accepting a `StdGen` and staying pure, or using the OS's random generator and staying in `IO`.  At some point, you'll have to make a call to the OS's random functionality to get a seed or value, but this can happen in `main` far away from your actual code.

To keep your functions pure, you'll need to pass around a `StdGen` and use the functions

```
random :: Random a => StdGen -> (a, StdGen)
randoms :: Random a => StdGen -> [a]
```

(Note: I've substituted `RandomGen g => g` for `StdGen`, there's no need to write a custom `RandomGen` instance for your case)

You can then write your function `generateMyKey` as

```
randomList :: Int -> StdGen -> [Int]
randomList n = take n . randoms

generateMyKey :: String -> StdGen -> String
generateMyKey text g
    = concatMap show
    $ map abs
    $ randomList (length text) g
```

And this entirely avoids having to live in `IO`.  Be wary, though, if you re-use the same `g`, you'll generate the same random list each time.  We can avoid this by using `IO` and its related functions

```
randomList :: Int -> IO [Int]
randomList 0 = return []
randomList n = do
    first <- randomIO
    rest <- randomList (n - 1)  -- Recursively generate the rest
    return $ first : rest

generateMyKey :: String -> IO String
generateMyKey text = do
    key <- randomList (length text)
    return $ concatMap show $ map abs $ key
```

This will come with a performance hit, and now we've lost the ability to generate the same key repeatedly, making it difficult to test our functions reliably!  How can we reconcile these two approaches?

---

Enter the package `MonadRandom`.  This package provides a monad (and monad transformer, but you don't need to worry about that right now) that lets you abstract away how you generate random numbers so that you can choose how you want to run your code in different circumstances.  If you want `IO`, you can use `IO`.  If you want to supply a seed, you can supply a seed.  It's very handy.  You can install it with `cabal install MonadRandom` and use it as

```
import Control.Monad.Random

randomList :: Int -> Rand StdGen [Int]
randomList n = fmap (take n) getRandoms

generateMyKey :: String -> Rand StdGen String
generateMyKey text = do
    key <- randomList (length text)
    return $ concatMap show $ map abs $ key
```

Our `generateMyKey` code is even the same as the `IO` version other than the type signature!

Now to run it.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- Entirely impure, have it automatically grab a StdGen from IO for us
    ioVersion <- evalRandIO $ generateMyKey "password"
    -- Make a StdGen that stays the same every time we run the program, useful for testing
    let pureStdGen = mkStdGen 12345
        pureVersion = evalRand (generateMyKey "password") pureStdGen
    -- Get a StdGen from the system, but still evaluate it purely
    ioStdGen <- getStdGen
    let pureVersion2 = evalRand (generateMyKey "password") ioStdGen
    -- Print out all three versions
    putStrLn ioVersion
    putStrLn pureVersion
    putStrLn pureVersion2
```